# Gnome Contacts doesn't show Nextcloud from Online Accounts

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, contacts

I am running Ubuntu 19.10. I have configured Online Accounts to access my Nextcloud server. I have turned on all the types of data (Files, Contacts, etc.).

Calendar and Contacts works with Lightning.

Calendar works with Gnome Calendar.

Contacts does not work with Gnome Contacts.

The starting Contacts Setup page has nothing listed to select. The box in the middle of the window is empty.

Why doesn't my Nextcloud source show up? Also, shouldn't there be some local address book that I can choose?

Thanks.

Comment: I know how to set Gnome Contacts up. It doesn't work. It doesn't find the Online Account I've configured for Nextcloud.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but I've been having similar one's. based on [this discussion on the fedora 32 pre-beta](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-32-pre-beta-including-issues-workarounds/17521/16) It seems like a known issue there.

Comment: Seems to be still the same with Ubuntu 22.04 – or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, Contacts is working correctly now in 22.04. It does get my contacts from NextCloud.